# Why they didn't work when I scrape the string in HTML by using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the tilte string "The Dormouse's story" in a HTML,using the beautifulsoup tool.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = """
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Dormouse's story</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b>
  </p>

  <p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
    <a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
    <a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
    <a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>; and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

  <p class="story">...</p>

  """ 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc) 
print soup.title.string
```

I use the Python2.7.9 IDE, and the error is describe as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Scripts/test.py", line 23, in <module>
    print soup.title.string
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1353, in write
    s = unicode.__getslice__(s, None, None)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

How can I solve this problem, should I need to change the type of the variable?

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with your installation. Your code works correctly at my machine. Note that the error comes from somewhere inside IDLE.

Comment: it works for me. I didn't find this `s = unicode.__getslice__(s, None, None)` line in your code.

Comment: I found this file https://github.com/nipy/pbrain/blob/master/pbrainlib/pyshell.py but it doesn't have 1,353 lines or any line that matches the error

Comment: There is a regression of a known bug in IDLE; use `print unicode(soup.title.string)`; see http://bugs.python.org/issue1757057. At least you didn't get an infinite recursion error anymore.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: that's the point; this is a bug in IDLE.

Comment: @Kos: no, I can easily reproduce the problem. Do `class Foo(unicode): pass`, then `print Foo()`, *in IDLE*, to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in IDLE when you run the script with the *Run Module* command; the work-around is to use `unicode()` on the object:

```
print unicode(soup.title.string)
```

The issue is caused by an incorrect fix for [issue 19481](http://bugs.python.org/issue19481); I suspect that the `unicode.__getslice__` method got cleaned up and / or never supported using `None` for the indices, at least in Python 2.

I've opened a [new bug on IDLE](http://bugs.python.org/issue23583) for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in your IDE, when i use it, no error.

```
 <<ret = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
 <<soup = BeautifulSoup(ret)
 <<print soup.title.string
 <<About Me
```